# Parse строки в оъект Protobuf Java

Tags: java, python, сокет, google-protobuf

Клиент-серверное приложение Python + Java, обмениваются сообщениями через сокет с использованием protobuf.

Структура файла Protobuf:

```
package tutorial;

option java_package = "com.example.tutorial";
option java_outer_classname = "mess";


message request {
  required float a = 1;
  required float b = 2;
  required float c = 3;
  }
message response {
    optional float x = 1;
    optional string mess = 2;
}
```

Клиент на python создает объект `request` потом отправляет его в сокет, сериализованный в строку КОД - `sock.send(Request.SerializeToString())`.

Как на сервере Java парсить эту строку, которая принялась в сокет? Нужно создавать объект `request`?

Comment: Ну если нету готовых парсеров, то придётся самому его делать на java. Ну и суть в том, что бы считать весь поток байтов из сокета, а потом уже работать с ней.